# Misunderstanding on the issue of continuity in the functional matrix

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb R^{d} \to \mathbb R^{\nu}$
I am having difficulty in understanding relevance of continuity in the functional matrix 
$\frac{\partial(f_{1},\ldots,f_{\nu})}{\partial(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})}$.

**Why do I say this**:
We recently proved that for a linear map $g: \mathbb R^{d} \to \mathbb R^{\nu}, g(x):=Ax$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{d \times \nu}$ matrix, $g$ is differentiable and $(Df)(x)=A$ **(*)**.

So surely by this statement, if the functional matrix $\frac{\partial(f_{1},\ldots,f_{\nu})}{\partial(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})}$ exists then it has to be differentiable in $x$ and that then implies it has to be continuous in $x$?

So then why am I asked to prove that:

$\partial_{k}f_{j}$ continuous $\forall k \in \{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $\forall j \in \{1,\ldots,\nu\} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial(f_{1},\ldots,f_{\nu})}{\partial(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})}$ continuous in $x$.

I have seen the proof for the above. But I do not understand why it cannot simply be deduced from the fact that if $\forall j \in \{1,\ldots,\nu\}$ $f_{j}$ is partially differentiable in $x$ then $\frac{\partial(f_{1},\ldots,f_{\nu})}{\partial(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})}$ exists in $x$ and by **(*)** we know that it is differential in $x$ and thereby also continuous in $x$.

What is wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: I believe you want to understand why the derivative matrix $Df(x) = \left[\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right]$ is continuous as $x$ varies, not continuous as a linear mapping for fixed $x$. But, given your hypotheses, this is just saying that if the entries of a matrix are continuous functions of $x$, then the matrix varies continuously.

Comment: But the derivative matrix is a linear mapping, is it not?

Comment: For fixed $x$, yes. But the question is asking you to see that the matrix varies continuously as $x$ varies. Think of the matrix as a giant vector with $d\nu$ entries. A vector function is continuous if and only if all its component functions are continuous.

Comment: So then partially continuously differentiable in $x$ implies $(Df)(x)$ continuous in $x$, as all entries are continuous in $x$. Does this then mean that $g: R^{d} \to R^{\nu}, g(x):=((Df)(x))(x)$ is continuous. Secondly I am a bit confused by the term of continuity for a variable $x$. Until now we've just studied continuity for a fixed $x$

Comment: Are we basically find the neighborhood around $x$ (let $\lambda$ be an element of this neighborhood) for which $(Df)(\lambda)$ is continuous?